# Permissions problems reading users from azure AD with User.ReadBasic.All?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, permissions, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get azure users and i am getting permissions error, even if instead of Users i place ME, why ? shouldnt it be something that i had no need to have admin consent? Any help is appreciated!!

````
            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create("****")
                .WithTenantId("****")
                .WithClientSecret("***")
                .Build();

            ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
            // Create a new instance of GraphServiceClient with the authentication provider.
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

            var user = await graphClient.Users
                .Request()
                .WithScopes(graphScopes)
                .Select(u => new {
                    u.DisplayName
                })
                .GetAsync();
    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem it seems you do not have permission to get the users. You can refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) of the graph api, you need the permission shown as below:

[image]

So please go to the application which registered in your azure ad, and click "**API permissions**", then add the permission into it.

[image]

[image]

After add the permissions, please do not forget click "**Grand admin consent for xxx**".

For the question why it still failed when you change the `Users` to `me`. You use client credential flow to do authentication to request the graph api, you just provide the information of `clientId`, `tenantId` and `clientSecret`. So it doesn't contain a user(or yourself) information. So you can't use `.Me`. If you want to use `.Me`, you can use [password grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc#authorization-request). It contains the user information, so system know who is `.Me`.

================================**Update**==============================

If you want to use delegated permission(such as `User.ReadBasic.All`), you can't use client_credential. Now your code use client_credential flow, the access token doesn't contain user identity. I provide a sample of username/password flow(and use delegated permission `User.ReadBasic.All`) below for your referencef:

In the "**API permissions**" tab of the registered app, I just add one permission `User.ReadBasic.All`.

[image]

The code shown as below:

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.Security;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create("<clientId>")
            .WithTenantId("<tenantId>")
            .Build();

            string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            UsernamePasswordProvider authProvider = new UsernamePasswordProvider(publicClientApplication, scopes);

            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

            var str = "<your password>";
            var password = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in str) password.AppendChar(c);

            var users = await graphClient.Users.Request().WithUsernamePassword("<your account/email>", password).GetAsync();

            Console.WriteLine(users.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

And before run the code, you need to do "consent to use the application" once. You need to browse the url as this: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<clientId>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=<redirectUri>&response_mode=query&scope=openid https://graph.microsoft.com/.default&state=12345` in your browser and the page will show as:
[image]

Click "**Accept**", then you can run the code to get user list success.

Comment: Thanks man, one thing that i dont understand, can´t i use delegated permissions?  if you read your own image, you have a scope called user.readbasic.all...
That permission/scope doesn´t need admin consent, and i wanted to use that! Is it possible ?  Or do i really need to ask for permission ? :o

Comment: I actually went to read a littlemore because you gave me a light, and what i think i want to use is on behalf of, but it seems that before i go call api to get to azure, i need to call another one to get my user before!  I dont know if i am right or not, but even if i am i have no idea of how to do that! so if you could also make a sample or something out would be great! :)

Comment: Hi @RicardoFigueiredo If you want to use delegated permission without admin consent, you can use username/password flow. You just need to do the user consent by yourself once before run the code. Please refer to the "Update" in my answer.